# Can't Turn off the notification sound using cordova-plugin-local-notification

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am using the [cordova-plugin-local-notification](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#properties) plugin and I can't seem to turn off the sound when the notification displays.

What I want: no sound nor any system sound when the notification plays,

What I've tried:

```
if (isAppPaused) {
   cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
   title: 'CHANGE',
   text: changeTime + "s",
   wakeup: false,
   vibrate: false,
   sound: null
   });
}
```

and

```
if (isAppPaused) {
  cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
  title: 'CHANGE',
  text: changeTime + "s",
  wakeup: false,
  vibrate: false,
  sound: false
  });
 }
```

Is it possible to turn off the sound when it's being displayed?

Thanks.